# Is this copper piping?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, plumbing-fixture, water-damage

Is the pipe in the picture copper piping? House is from 1962, I assume this is original piping. The valve is leaking and I want to replace it with a sharkbite valve[image]

Comment: Where exactly is it leaking from?  Have you tried tightening the nut  on the valve stem?

Comment: @JACK it's leaking from around the bonnet nut area. I already tried tightening the nut but to no avail. It's on there pretty tight and still leaks. I thinking of replacing it with a 1" sharkbite valve. I think it's 1" in diameter

Comment: You should be able to remove and repack the gasket material that seals the stem in the bonnet.  Used to be done with a twine impregnated with wax(?), IIRC.

Comment: Your problem with a sharkbite is that the system expects a clean/round pipe. You've got solder drool and paint. So, I'd suggest a repack/rebuild, learn to solder, or pay someone to do it.

Comment: Oh, and if you're in the US, that's probably 3/4 copper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like the fittings are soldered, so that would mean copper.  Can you gently scrape some of the gray paint off - it already appears to be flaking off in places - and see if the copper color shows?

Comment: A wire brush should shine up the horizontal run as an additional confirmation.

Comment: Or a magnet, because the other option is iron.

Comment: I'm seeing copper colour in the tool mark 2" above the valve.